# Application still says file is open and display error

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a txt file that is loaded into a listbox when the form loads. Im trying to get this button to add to the text file. It says the file is still open. Is there a way I can make this add the path of the file selected to the listbox even if open. I'm not sure how to close this. I've been told it automatically does it.

```
private void shortcutManagerForm_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (File.Exists("Shortcut_Items.txt"))
  {
    shortcutListBox.DataSource = File.ReadAllLines("Shortcut_Items.txt");
  }
}

OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();

if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
{
  string tempPath = "";
  tempPath = openFileDialog1.FileName;
  StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("Shortcut_Items.txt", true);
  string path = "Shortcut_Items.txt";
  string appendText = Environment.NewLine + tempPath + Environment.NewLine;
  File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);
  MessageBox.Show("Shortcut added");
}
```

Comment: Why are you opening a file handle to the `file2` variable and then never using it?  You could dispose of that object, but you don't seem to even need it in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("Shortcut_Items.txt", true);
// ...
File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);
```

Sure, the file is open. You create a StreamWriter that opens that file for writing. Then - completely independently of that StreamWriter - you open the file for writing *again* using File.AppendAllText.

Get rid of your StreamWriter code entirely. If you're using File.AppendAllText, you don't *need* a StreamWriter - File.AppendAllText is self-contained.

Answer (score 1):

You are never CLOSING the file.  I would recommend the 'using' statement which will automatically close your file for you.

Replace this portion of your code:

```
StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("Shortcut_Items.txt", true);
string path = "Shortcut_Items.txt";
string appendText = Environment.NewLine + tempPath + Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);
```

With this:

```
using(StreamWriter file2 = new StreamWriter("Shortcut_Items.txt", true))
{
  //Do whatever you're going to do with the file
}

string path = "Shortcut_Items.txt";
string appendText = Environment.NewLine + tempPath + Environment.NewLine;
File.AppendAllText(path, appendText);
```

Comment: Why use file2 if you aren't going to use it either?

Comment: And if the `StreamWriter` is locking the file then `File.AppendAllText` will still fail even with this code, you'd have to move it outside the `using`.

Comment: Ok, I updated my answer.  I'm assuming the person asking the original question removed some of their code for brevity...